# WPF Executing function in user control on application close?

Tags: wpf

I have a bunch of user controls in my application. When I close my application, I want to fire off some specific functions in each of these user controls one-by-one. Is this possible? The `Unloaded` event doesn't seem to get fired on application close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can register to

```
Application.Current.Exit
```

in each UserControl.xaml.cs:

```
        public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Application.Current.Exit += CurrentOnExit;
    }

    private void CurrentOnExit(object sender, ExitEventArgs exitEventArgs)
    {
        Application.Current.Exit -= CurrentOnExit;
        //Do what you want
    }
```

Comment: You can register in contructor